# C# библиотека для поиска элементов на сайте

Tags: c#

Подскажите библиотеку на C#, чтобы по требуемому `id`, `class` или каким-либо другим характеристикам, доставать или записывать значения, к примеру в какой-нибудь input?

Comment: Вы говорите про веб-приложение? Вы говорите про парсинг данных? Приведите пример задачи на _запись_ значений. Пока вопрос непонятен.

Comment: @AK судя по `или записывать значения, к примеру в какой-нибудь input` тут selenium нужен, но своими руками я с ним не работал, так что могу и ошибаться.

Comment: @rdorn предпочитаю не гадать, если есть возможность спросить у топикстартера.

Comment: Допустим, надо зайти на сайт, в строке поиска ввести слово и нажать на кнопку "поиск". какие есть для этого библиотеки?

Comment: Какие? Очень разные. Для начала нужно вообще понять, что можно делать как без браузера -- слать запросы через WebClient или AngleSharp или что там ещё; можно устроить мини-браузер IE прямо в приложении winforms, можно управлять внешним браузером через специальные плагины, а можно делать это через Selenium. Когда вы выберете одно из четырёх направлений под свои конкретные задачи (про которые до сих пор не слова), тогда только мы сможем говорить о конкретных библиотеках. Для написания тестов например стандарт де-факто - это Селениум, но если вам не тесты, то это совет "мимо кассы". Что надо-то?

Answer (score 3):

> Допустим, надо зайти на сайт, в строке поиска ввести слово и нажать на кнопку "поиск". какие есть для этого библиотеки?

Вы пишете бот. Библиотеки есть двух видов:

1. Браузерные "движки", конкретнее - Awesomium, CEF, если совсем новичок и подключить стороннюю библиотеку для вас проблема - то WebBrowser, который на "Панели элементов", но учтите, что WebBrowser - это Internet Explorer, притом старой версии, и многие сайты в нем просто не работают как надо.
2. Библиотеки, поддерживающие только HTTP-запросы и парсинг HTML. В принципе. во многих случаях этого варианта достаточно.
   **Замечу: AJAX (например, "бесконечная загрузка" при скролле во ВКонтакте) - это тоже HTTP-запросы, поэтому если освоить Fiddler (или другой сниффер) и сами HTML & CSS & JS (что в любом случае надо сделать), то и AJAX не будет проблемой.**
   Для HTTP-запросов именно для ботов рекомендую xNet (это самописная реализация HTTP на базе TCP, поэтому в теории можно в точности повторять запросы, вплоть до порядка хедеров и т.д., и это так и будет если висходнике убрать дефолтные хедеры и пересобрать), для парсинга HTML - HtmlAgilityPack, еще есть такая вещь как JSON, для нее библиотека Json.NET.

**И еще:** на некоторых сайтах есть открытое API, поэтому не надо ничего парсить, готовые ответы в удобном формате, как правило JSON, соответственно библиотеки: xNet + Json.NET.
Но вот авторизацию oAuth на первый раз не просто понять. И может потребоваться все-таки браузерный "движок" для получения токена при OAuth, например в VK API он нужен.

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете использовать NuGet пакет [Selenium Web Driver](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Selenium.WebDriver/) Visual Studio. Он как раз для этого + низкий порог вхождения.

[Вот](http://toolsqa.com/selenium-c-sharp/), вроде неплохая инструкция